# How to show button after refreshing the page with delay time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created one small function, what I want, after refreshing the page, is the button to show with some delay time..

I mean, for example, if I click the `modify` div, the page is going to refresh and show the button with 5000ms delay ( Refresh after 5000ms delay then the button wants to show).

Here is my fiddle..

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/ucytp0o7/)**

I hope my question is understandable..

Here is my example snippet here..

```js
// after page refresh show button with 5000ms delay

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#modify_sec").click(function() {
    location.reload();
  }, 5000);
  $("#sec_get").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right cash-icons">

    <li class="breadcrumb-item mdfy_icon" id="modify_sec"><a href="#">Modify</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>

<!-- button -->

<div class="col-2">
  <div class="data_btn" id="sec_get">
    <button type="button" id="getBtn">Get data</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set a timeout with a delay you want in milliseconds :

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("#sec_get").show(); }, 5000);
```

Comment: Same here bro! i dont need to show button everytime refresh.. means if i click F5, it will shown the button, i dont need that, i want only click this function refresh page and show the button..

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you. I have tested this on fiddle but i think the code wont work here due to LocalStorage.

```js
// after page refresh show button
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#modify_sec").click(function() {
        window.localStorage.setItem("isLink", false);
        location.reload();
    });
  if(window.localStorage.getItem("isLink"))
   $('#modify_sec').addClass('hide');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#sec_get").removeClass('hide');
  },5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right cash-icons">

    <li class="breadcrumb-item mdfy_icon" id="modify_sec"><a href="#">Modify</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>

<!-- button -->

<div class="col-2">
  <div class="data_btn hide" id="sec_get">
    <button type="button" id="getBtn">Get data</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes bro! but i dont need to show everytime refresh.. means if i click F5 it will shown the button, i dont need that, i want only click this function refresh page and show the button..

Comment: It means when clicking on link, then only show button after few second, and when the f5 it should show instantely, right?

Comment: No no no!! i dont want to show this button instantely, when i click this link, the page wants to refresh and show the button only..

Comment: @Joe I have update my answer, We can use localStorage to keep the track on button click.